# asp insert into database duplicate data

Tags: oracle, asp-classic

I got a class ASP website recently. and got a weird issue.

Language: ASP.

Database: Oracle,

When I insert into database. in case have the duplicated data(here ignore the oracle primary key setting.it's an old system,we'd better not change the database.)
then we have the validate before insert into DB:

```
sql="select 1 from tablename where condition...."
result=runsql(sql)
if not result.eof then
 'here means DB has data already then we return false. and exit the function.
 exit function
 end if

 'Insert Into DB statement
```

I use batch file upload. means the file have many records. for example,50 records.
then we use two computer open this website and click submit button to upload file at the same time.

we found the database has some duplicate data.only part of them, not all.

I don't know this what happened. we have add the validate already before insert into DB.

Can someone help me this?

this website don't have the thread something.

Comment: Look up "race condition". Best of luck.

Comment: So have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a race condition in your code. Logically it appears that your code looks like the following:

```
Open file

Repeat
  Read record from file
  Check if record exists in table
  If no record in table
    Add record to table
End repeat

Close file
```

The race condition is that if you have two processes executing, each one may check to see if a particular record exists in the table; both will get back a return value indicating that the record does not exist; and both will then proceed to insert the record. You apparently don't have a primary or unique key constraint in the database to prevent duplicate data, and thus the data inserted by each process is added to the table.

The situation you've encountered occurs because two processes do not know what each other is doing. Each is scheduled independently and share the processor(s) not just between themselves but with all other processes running at the same time, and their execution is interrupted unpredictably to allow other processes to run. Now, let's consider the following scenario:

```
Process 1 starts
Process 2 starts
Process 1 issues an I/O request to read a record from the
  file, relinquishing the CPU
Process 2 issues an I/O request to read a record from the
  file, relinquishing the CPU
I/O for process 1 completes and process 1 is rescheduled for execution
I/O for process 2 completes and process 2 is rescheduled for execution
Process 2 executes, issues an SQL request to see if the record exists in the
  table, and relinquishes the CPU
Process 1 executes, issues the same SQL request, and relinquish the CPU
SQL request for process 2 completes; process 2 is rescheduled for execution
SQL request for process 1 completes; process 1 is rescheduled for execution
Process 1 executes and finds the record does not exist in the file
  Process 1 adds the record to the file
Process 2 executes and finds the record does not exist in the file
  Process 2 adds the record to the file
```

Note that the execution order of the processes has swapped around a couple of times. This is normal - you have no control over which process will be scheduled for execution, nor do you need to care about it.

Each of your processes has found, correctly, that the record from the file did not exist when it looked at the database, and thus added it. Unfortunately, each of your processes did not know that another process was doing exactly the same thing at more-or-less the same time.

IMO the easiest thing to do would be to have each process attempt to lock the file so that only it could read the file. This would prevent other processes from reading and processing data from the file, thus preventing this kind of issue. It looks like you're using VB.Net, so you should be able to use [FileSystem.Lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/737da975(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to lock the file. The logical flow of your program would be changed to look like:

```
Open file

Lock the file
  - either wait until the file can be locked successfully or terminate because the
    file is in use by another process

Repeat
  Read record from file
  Check if record exists in table
  If no record in table
    Add record to table
End repeat

Unlock the file

Close file
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks your patient and details reply. Sorry for that one question about the lock, different PC upload different file. only the file has the duplicate data. if lock the file,means this file cannot share to read. but we upload different files. this way is ok ?